# PHPunit call magic methods

Tags: unit-testing, methods, mocking, phpunit, magic-methods

I have magic method `getData`. Is it possible to call following inside unit test:

```
    $this->attributeMock
        ->method('getData')
        ->with('additional_data')
        ->willReturn('some value');

    $this->attributeMock
        ->method('getData')
        ->with('is_default')
        ->willReturn('something');
```

When I do this, I got:

```
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual @@ @@
-'is_default'
+'additional_data'
```

Is there some another way?

Comment: Can you post more code of the test scenario and a piece of code of the class you are mocking? I suspect your code is right you are only missing the `at` directive for specify in with invocation of the same method you want the correct mocked result, as esample: `$this->attributeMock->expects($this->at(1))
        ->method('getData')
        ->with('additional_data')
        ->willReturn('some value');` and     `$this->attributeMock->expects($this->at(0))
        ->method('getData')
        ->with('is_default')
        ->willReturn('something');`

Comment: Thanks for your response, the problem was with missing `at` directive. Post your comment as answer. As it was helpful I will mark it.

Comment: Hi @zhartaunik you are welcome! I don't post directly as an answer because if you are using the real php magic method `__call` the code was little different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the PHPUnit `at()` method to check method invocation at certain index.

So you can use the following code:

```
$this->attributeMock
    ->expects($this->at(1))
    ->method('getData')
    ->with('additional_data')
    ->willReturn('some value');

$this->attributeMock
    ->expects($this->at(0))
    ->method('getData')
    ->with('is_default')
    ->willReturn('something');
```

You can check the following article for some reference:

http://www.andrejfarkas.com/2012/07/phpunit-at-method-to-check-method-invocation-at-certain-index/